# Custom Post Type and Taxonomy Permalink Rewrite in WordPress 3.0.1

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, taxonomy, permalinks, custom-post-type

I have a *'story'* **Custom Post Type** and *'artist', writer'* **Taxonomies**.

I need to set **rewrite rules** in the functions.php for the **permalinks** to look like this:

**Artist** (Taxonomy/Category):
http://www.example.com/isaac-deutscher
(*/%artist%*)

**Writer** (Taxonomy/Category):
http://www.example.com/jean-paul-sartre
(*/%writer%*)

**Story** (Custom Post Type):
http://www.example.com/issac-deutscher/jean-paul-sartre/the-cat-is-under-the-table
(*/%artist%/%writer%/%story%*)

I have tried some code I found in blogs without success, and can't figure out how to solve this.

I'm working in **Wordpress 3.0.1**

Answer (score 3):

This does the trick for Story and Artist, but not for Writer:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_init');
add_filter('post_type_link', 'story_permalink', 10, 3);

function custom_init(){  
    $story = array(  
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => false,
    );
    $artist = array(
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true
    );
    $writer = array(
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true
    );  

    register_post_type('story', $story);
    register_taxonomy('artist', 'story', $artist);
    register_taxonomy('writer', 'story', $writer);

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $story_structure = '/%artist%/%writer%/%story%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%story%", '([^/]+)', "story=");
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('story', $story_structure, false);
}

function story_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename){
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    $rewritecode = array(
    '%artist%',
    '%writer%',
    $leavename? '' : '%postname%',
    $leavename? '' : '%pagename%',
    );

    if('' != $permalink && !in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))){

        if (strpos($permalink, '%artist%') !== FALSE){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'artist');  
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $artist = $terms[0]->slug;
        else $artist = 'unassigned-artist';         
        }

    if (strpos($permalink, '%writer%') !== FALSE){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'writer');  
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $writer = $terms[0]->slug;
        else $writer = 'unassigned-writer';         
    }           

    $rewritereplace = array(
        $artist,
        $writer,
        $post->post_name,
        $post->post_name,
    );
    $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink);
    }
    else{
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @maukoquiroga! I've copied your code and modified it a bit, I've replaced the cpt and taxonomy names and removed the writer taxonomy completely. Can't get it to work though, only get 404's. Think you can help me? Please have a look: 
http://pastebin.com/Q19amsZL

Comment: I have been breaking my head and looking around for this solution since weeks. This 12 years old code still works. Thank you.