# How to create a custom post type template for a custom URL with taxonomy term in it?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress v6.0.2, I have a custom taxonomy `country` and a custom post_type `interest`.

With `post_type_link` filter (another working function) and with the below function, I am rewriting custom post_type URLs as `https://www.example.com/country_name/interest_term`:

```
    add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'country_cpt_generating_rule');

    function country_cpt_generating_rule($wp_rewrite) {
    $rules = array();
    $terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'country',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    $post_type = 'interest';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {

        $rules[$term->slug . '/interest/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?interest=$matches[1]&post_type=' . $post_type . 'name=$matches[1]';
    }

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

While I have `single-interest.php` custom post_type template to show custom content, single posts are redirecting to home page with `error404` class added to the body.

A `var_dump(get_queried_object());` returning `null`.

I have flushed permalinks and also tried checking `is_singular()` to template redirecting, that did not worked.

How can I have a custom page template for `single-interest` with above custom URL?

Comment: Is this  `$post_type = 'inrerest';` a typo?  If yes is this just in the SO Q or also your code?

Comment: It is a typo here. In my actual code is it `$post_type = 'interest';`. I have corrected in my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken cue from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3861323/3725816) and below code worked for me:

```
// custom url
add_action('init', 'custom_init');
add_filter('post_type_link', 'interest_permalink', 10, 3);

function custom_init() {

global $wp_rewrite;
$interest_structure = '/%country%/%interest%';
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%interest%", '([^/]+)', "interest=");
$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('interest', $interest_structure, false);
}

function interest_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
$post = get_post($post_id);

$rewritecode = array(
    '%country%',
    $leavename ? '' : '%postname%',
);

if ('' != $permalink && !in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))) {

    if (strpos($permalink, '%country%') !== FALSE) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'country');
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) {
            $country = $terms[0]->slug;
        } else {
            $country = 'unassigned_country';
        }
    }

    $countryreplace = array(
        $country,
        $post->post_name,
    );
    $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $countryreplace, $permalink);
} else {
    
}
return $permalink;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the complete solution for your requirement. Please note that you do not have to regenerate new rewrite rules to be able to work with custom post-type URLs. instead, I have used filters to modify URLs based on your need. Let me know if this solves your issue. Please do not forget to flush your permalinks. There might be some edge cases that I did not put my focus on because mainly I was focusing on achieving your requirements.

```
add_action('init', 'register_cpt_type');

add_filter('pre_term_link', 'change_term_links', 10, 2);

function change_term_links( $termlink, $term ) {
    $post_type = isset( get_taxonomy( $term->taxonomy )->object_type[0] ) ? get_taxonomy( $term->taxonomy )->object_type[0] : '';

    if( $post_type === 'interest' ) {
        $termlink = explode('/', $termlink) != '' ? explode('/', $termlink): '';
        unset($termlink[1]);
        $termlink = implode('', $termlink);
    }

    return $termlink;
}

function register_cpt_type() {

    $args = array(
        'label'               => 'Interest',
        'description'         => 'Add new interest from here',
        'public'              => true,
        'public_queryable'    => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'rewrite'             => array(
            'slug'       => '%country%',
            'with_front' => false        
        ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'show_in_rest'        => true,
        'with_front'          => false,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-chart-pie',
        'supports'            => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'author', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'comments')
    );

    register_post_type('interest', $args);

    $args = array(
        'label'        => 'Country',
        'public'       => true,
        'show_ui'      => true,
        'query_var'    => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite'      => array(
            'slug'       => '%country%',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
    );
    
    register_taxonomy( 'country', 'interest', $args );

}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'single_cpt_postlink', 10, 2);

function single_cpt_postlink( $post_link, $post ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID ) != '' ? get_post_type( $post->ID ) : '';

    if( $post_type == 'interest' ) {
        $term_slug = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'country' ) != '' ? get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'country' )[0]->slug : '';
        if( ! empty( $term_slug ) ) {
            $post_link = str_replace('%country%', $term_slug, $post_link);
        }
    }

    return $post_link;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are wanting to access the CPT single page. In order to do that please follow the code below

```
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_interest_single_template' ), 99);

function get_interest_single_template( $single_template_path ) {

        if (is_singular('interest')) {
            $single_template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/single-interest.php' ;

        }

        return $single_template;

}
```

Now inside the "single-interest.php". you can var_dump( get_queried_object() ). Which should give you the values of the WP_Post Object data. Since this template is directly coming from a plugin the custom template file should be placed inside a plugin or the custom single-interest file should be placed inside the theme file in this format "single-interest.php". Also, I would like to add the following points, since you are using a custom post type, you do not have to regenerate custom slugs. Because WordPress does regenerate the custom slugs for you. I would recommend you not use 'generate_rewrite_rules' because WordPress did create those slugs for you while creating the custom post type. What you can do is pass the slug value inside the 'parse_request' filter hook. For reference please refer to this page [here](https://therichpost.com/wordpress-parse_query-working-example/)

Comment: As of now my `single-interest.php` page is accessible through `www.example.com/post_type-slug/post-slug`. What I am trying to have is `www.example.com/custom-taxonomy-slug/post-slug`.

Comment: Basically, this process is lengthy, and I don't have enough amount of words to write in this comment. I would recommend you to read this once https://therichpost.com/wordpress-parse_query-working-example/